# Segue from CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used this segue many times in swift, but I cannot make it work from a collectionViewCell.  Why????

I have control + drag from the cell to a ViewController

Here is my code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "followSegue", sender: self.postsFollow[indexPath.item].follower)


    print(self.postsFollow[indexPath.item].follower)

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}

//Segue to show username in FindUserViewController
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier! == "followSegue" {
        let guest = segue.destination as! FindUserViewController
        guest.pickedUser = sender as! String


        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = "Back"
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

    }
}
```

Comment: instead of making a segue from the cell to FindUserViewController, Select the CollectionVC and drag the segue to FindUserViewController.

Comment: Thanks. I works :-)

Comment: your welcome :-) Happy coding